# Trigger.io - You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded

Tags: android, trigger.io

I configured the In-app payment, but a consumable product once from apple store and when i try to buy it again it said "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded", i click ok to download it, and it does not work, i've read a ton of post and it seams not to work in trigger.io, I can not understand how can i pay trigger.io every month and thay stiull have a tons of problems and nobody want to answer my emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message normally means the purchase event has been sent to your app but you have not confirmed the transaction.

Make sure you have a listener set up for `transactionReceived` see the docs for more details and example code: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/payments.html#forgepaymentstransactionreceivedaddlistenercallback

I also recommend you read through https://trigger.io/docs/current/recipes/payments.html if you haven't already, it includes details on how to test your payments code is working properly.

Comment: I have read the document a 100 times, i have configured everything, the problems stays in iOS. If you try it for yourself you will see it.

Comment: It would be useful to see the code you are using, could you either include it in your question here, or zip up your app and send it to support@trigger.io

Comment: Go to apple store. Find Facerage, download it, buy 2 packs of cheapest coins, on second purchase you will see. Send me your paypal account I will refund your 1.78 EUR.

Comment: If it doesn't work on the 2nd time then it sounds like you are not calling the confirm() callback correctly when you receive the transaction event. To look into this more I will need access to your code.